# obiee 11g installation stuck at 14 of 15 steps

Tags: oracle11g, obiee, weblogic11g

I'm installing OBIEE 11.1.1.9.0 on my windows server 2019 standard Evaluation,

I'm stuck at 14th of 15 steps please find the screen shot below for that
[image]

it stuck at 26% for more than 2 hours and the elapsed time is keep on increasing

my server hardware free space is

```
> 16 ram and 25-30 GB hard disk free memory
and OS is windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about installing on Windows 2019 and then you say Windows 10. That's contradictory but actually doesn't matter because neither is supported. OBI 11.1.1.9 is ages old and only ever supported up to Windows 2012R2.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi/bi-11gr1certmatrix-11-1-1-9-0-2541437.xls

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual machine make sure that the number of CPU cores you are using is >= 2, this is one of the issues that makes the installation freeze.